# Error when building Flutter v2.8.1 iOS app on M1 MacBook. : error=-402652958: Error Domain=com.apple.dtdevicekit Code=806

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios, flutter-ios-build

I am developing a Flutter v2.8.1 app on M1 MacBook.
There is a problem when building with iOS.

I've tried all sorts of ways for a long time, but nothing works.

The same project builds fine on Intel MacBook.

I also ran the command below.

```
> sudo gem install ffi
> sudo gem install cocoapods
```

When building for iOS, the following error occurs.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 13 in debug mode...
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           42.9s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2022-02-24 16:35:23.257 xcodebuild[41435:8807886]  DTDeviceKit: Failed to mount DDI from '<DVTFilePath:0x6000004a8000:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/15.0/DeveloperDiskImage.dmg'>', error=-402653066: Error Domain=com.apple.dtdevicekit Code=806 "Failed to prepare device for development." UserInfo={AssociatedMobileDeviceFunction=AMDeviceMountImage, NSUnderlyingError=0x600003838c00 {Error Domain=com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain Code=-402653066 "Could not support development." UserInfo={MobileDeviceErrorCode=(0xE8000076), com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace=(
        0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000107436ff8 DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 272
        1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001074703bc -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken _mountDeveloperDiskImage:withError:] + 912
        2   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000107470db0 __58-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken mountDeveloperDiskImageWithError:]_block_invoke + 564
        3   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018250abac _dispatch_client_callout + 20
        4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000182519e00 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56
        5   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000107470b20 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken mountDeveloperDiskImageWithError:] + 168
        6   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000010e839070 __37-[DVTiOSDevice(Connect) hasConnected]_block_invoke_2 + 148
        7   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000102116238 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 16
        8   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000102119ba8 __DVTDispatchGroupAsync_block_invoke + 564
        9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000182508e60 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
        10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018250abac _dispatch_client_callout + 20
        11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018250e118 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 656
        12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018250d6dc _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 596
        13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018251c31c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 396
        14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018251cb58 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 164
        15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001826c5574 _pthread_wqthread + 228
        16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001826c42c4 start_wqthread + 8
    ), DVTRadarComponentKey=261622, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not support development.}}, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=If you are certain that Xcode supports development on this device, try disconnecting and reconnecting the device., NSLocalizedFailure=This operation can fail if the version of the OS on the device is newer than the version of Xcode that is running., DVTRadarComponentKey=487927, NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to prepare device for development.}
    2022-02-24 16:35:23.260 xcodebuild[41435:8807886]  iPhoneConnect: <DVTiOSDevice (0x1168722b0), Raymond’s iPhone13, iPhone, 15.4 (19E5219e), 00008110-001C3DD93A29801E> unable to mount developer disk image, (Error Domain=com.apple.dtdevicekit Code=806 "Failed to prepare device for development." UserInfo={AssociatedMobileDeviceFunction=AMDeviceMountImage, NSUnderlyingError=0x600003838c00 {Error Domain=com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain Code=-402653066 "Could not support development." UserInfo={MobileDeviceErrorCode=(0xE8000076), com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace=(
        0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000107436ff8 DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 272
        1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001074703bc -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken _mountDeveloperDiskImage:withError:] + 912
        2   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000107470db0 __58-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken mountDeveloperDiskImageWithError:]_block_invoke + 564
        3   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018250abac _dispatch_client_callout + 20
        4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000182519e00 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56
        5   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000107470b20 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken mountDeveloperDiskImageWithError:] + 168
        6   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000010e839070 __37-[DVTiOSDevice(Connect) hasConnected]_block_invoke_2 + 148
        7   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000102116238 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 16
        8   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000102119ba8 __DVTDispatchGroupAsync_block_invoke + 564
        9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000182508e60 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
        10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018250abac _dispatch_client_callout + 20
        11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018250e118 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 656
        12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018250d6dc _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 596
        13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018251c31c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 396
        14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018251cb58 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 164
        15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001826c5574 _pthread_wqthread + 228
        16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001826c42c4 start_wqthread + 8
    ), DVTRadarComponentKey=261622, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not support development.}}, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=If you are certain that Xcode supports development on this device, try disconnecting and reconnecting the device., NSLocalizedFailure=This operation can fail if the version of the OS on the device is newer than the version of Xcode that is running., DVTRadarComponentKey=487927, NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to prepare device for development.}) {
        AssociatedMobileDeviceFunction = AMDeviceMountImage;
        DVTRadarComponentKey = 487927;
        NSLocalizedDescription = "Failed to prepare device for development.";
        NSLocalizedFailure = "This operation can fail if the version of the OS on the device is newer than the version of Xcode that is running.";
        NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion = "If you are certain that Xcode supports development on this device, try disconnecting and reconnecting the device.";
        NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain Code=-402653066 \"Could not support development.\" UserInfo={MobileDeviceErrorCode=(0xE8000076), com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace=(\n\t0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000107436ff8 DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 272\n\t1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001074703bc -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken _mountDeveloperDiskImage:withError:] + 912\n\t2   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000107470db0 __58-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken mountDeveloperDiskImageWithError:]_block_invoke + 564\n\t3   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018250abac _dispatch_client_callout + 20\n\t4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000182519e00 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56\n\t5   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000107470b20 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken mountDeveloperDiskImageWithError:] + 168\n\t6   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000010e839070 __37-[DVTiOSDevice(Connect) hasConnected]_block_invoke_2 + 148\n\t7   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000102116238 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 16\n\t8   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000102119ba8 __DVTDispatchGroupAsync_block_invoke + 564\n\t9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000182508e60 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32\n\t10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018250abac _dispatch_client_callout + 20\n\t11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018250e118 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 656\n\t12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018250d6dc _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 596\n\t13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018251c31c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 396\n\t14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018251cb58 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 164\n\t15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001826c5574 _pthread_wqthread + 228\n\t16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001826c42c4 start_wqthread + 8\n), DVTRadarComponentKey=261622, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not support development.}";
    }
    2022-02-24 16:35:23.260 xcodebuild[41435:8807867] [MT] iPhoneConnect: <DVTiOSDevice (0x1168722b0), Raymond’s iPhone13, iPhone, 15.4 (19E5219e), 00008110-001C3DD93A29801E> -- An error occurred whilst preparing device for development -- Failed to prepare device for development.
    Domain: com.apple.dtdevicekit
    Code: 806
    Recovery Suggestion: If you are certain that Xcode supports development on this device, try disconnecting and reconnecting the device.
    User Info: {
        AssociatedMobileDeviceFunction = AMDeviceMountImage;
        DVTRadarComponentKey = 487927;
        NSLocalizedFailure = "This operation can fail if the version of the OS on the device is newer than the version of Xcode that is running.";
    }
    --
    Could not support development.
    Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
    Code: -402653066
    User Info: {
        DVTRadarComponentKey = 261622;
        MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8000076)";
        "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
        0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000107436ff8 DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 272
        1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001074703bc -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken _mountDeveloperDiskImage:withError:] + 912
        2   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000107470db0 __58-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken mountDeveloperDiskImageWithError:]_block_invoke + 564
        3   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018250abac _dispatch_client_callout + 20
        4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000182519e00 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56
        5   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000107470b20 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken mountDeveloperDiskImageWithError:] + 168
        6   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000010e839070 __37-[DVTiOSDevice(Connect) hasConnected]_block_invoke_2 + 148
        7   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000102116238 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 16
        8   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000102119ba8 __DVTDispatchGroupAsync_block_invoke + 564
        9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000182508e60 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
        10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018250abac _dispatch_client_callout + 20
        11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018250e118 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 656
        12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018250d6dc _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 596
        13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018251c31c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 396
        14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018251cb58 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 164
        15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001826c5574 _pthread_wqthread + 228
        16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001826c42c4 start_wqthread + 8
    );
    }
    --
    2022-02-24 16:35:23.260 xcodebuild[41435:8807867] [MT] iPhoneConnect: <DVTiOSDevice (0x1168722b0), Raymond’s iPhone13, iPhone, 15.4 (19E5219e), 00008110-001C3DD93A29801E> == Underlying device preparation errors ==
    2022-02-24 16:35:23.260 xcodebuild[41435:8807867] [MT] iPhoneConnect: Failed to prepare device for development.
    Domain: com.apple.dtdevicekit
    Code: 806
    Recovery Suggestion: If you are certain that Xcode supports development on this device, try disconnecting and reconnecting the device.
    User Info: {
        AssociatedMobileDeviceFunction = AMDeviceMountImage;
        DVTRadarComponentKey = 487927;
        NSLocalizedFailure = "This operation can fail if the version of the OS on the device is newer than the version of Xcode that is running.";
    }
    --
    Could not support development.
    Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
    Code: -402653066
    User Info: {
        DVTRadarComponentKey = 261622;
        MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8000076)";
        "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
        0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000107436ff8 DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 272
        1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001074703bc -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken _mountDeveloperDiskImage:withError:] + 912
        2   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000107470db0 __58-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken mountDeveloperDiskImageWithError:]_block_invoke + 564
        3   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018250abac _dispatch_client_callout + 20
        4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000182519e00 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56
        5   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000107470b20 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken mountDeveloperDiskImageWithError:] + 168
        6   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000010e839070 __37-[DVTiOSDevice(Connect) hasConnected]_block_invoke_2 + 148
        7   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000102116238 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 16
        8   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000102119ba8 __DVTDispatchGroupAsync_block_invoke + 564
        9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000182508e60 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
        10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018250abac _dispatch_client_callout + 20
        11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018250e118 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 656
        12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018250d6dc _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 596
        13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018251c31c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 396
        14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018251cb58 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 164
        15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001826c5574 _pthread_wqthread + 228
        16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001826c42c4 start_wqthread + 8
    );
    }
    --
    2022-02-24 16:35:23.260 xcodebuild[41435:8807867] [MT] iPhoneConnect: <DVTiOSDevice (0x1168722b0), Raymond’s iPhone13, iPhone, 15.4 (19E5219e), 00008110-001C3DD93A29801E> == END: Underlying device preparation errors ==
    2022-02-24 16:35:23.892 xcodebuild[41435:8807886]  DTDeviceKit: Failed to mount DDI from '<DVTFilePath:0x6000004a8000:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/15.0/DeveloperDiskImage.dmg'>', error=-402653066: Error Domain=com.apple.dtdevicekit Code=806 "Failed to prepare device for development." UserInfo={AssociatedMobileDeviceFunction=AMDeviceMountImage, NSUnderlyingError=0x600003b0c840 {Error Domain=com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain Code=-402653066 "Could not support development." UserInfo={MobileDeviceErrorCode=(0xE8000076), com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace=(
        0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000107436ff8 DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 272
        1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001074703bc -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken _mountDeveloperDiskImage:withError:] + 912
        2   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000107470db0 __58-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken mountDeveloperDiskImageWithError:]_block_invoke + 564
        3   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018250abac _dispatch_client_callout + 20
        4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000182519e00 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56
        5   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000107470b20 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken mountDeveloperDiskImageWithError:] + 168
        6   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000010e839070 __37-[DVTiOSDevice(Connect) hasConnected]_block_invoke_2 + 148
        7   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000102116238 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 16
        8   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000102119ba8 __DVTDispatchGroupAsync_block_invoke + 564
        9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000182508e60 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
        10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018250abac _dispatch_client_callout + 20
        11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018250e118 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 656
        12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018250d6dc _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 596
        13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018251c31c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 396
        14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018251cb58 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 164
        15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001826c5574 _pthread_wqthread + 228
        16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001826c42c4 start_wqthread + 8
    ), DVTRadarComponentKey=261622, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not support development.}}, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=If you are certain that Xcode supports development on this device, try disconnecting and reconnecting the device., NSLocalizedFailure=This operation can fail if the version of the OS on the device is newer than the version of Xcode that is running., DVTRadarComponentKey=487927, NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to prepare device for development.}
    2022-02-24 16:35:23.892 xcodebuild[41435:8807886]  iPhoneConnect: <DVTiOSDevice (0x1168722b0), Raymond’s iPhone13, iPhone, 15.4 (19E5219e), 00008110-001C3DD93A29801E> unable to mount developer disk image, (Error Domain=com.apple.dtdevicekit Code=806 "Failed to prepare device for development." UserInfo={AssociatedMobileDeviceFunction=AMDeviceMountImage, NSUnderlyingError=0x600003b0c840 {Error Domain=com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain Code=-402653066 "Could not support development." UserInfo={MobileDeviceErrorCode=(0xE8000076), com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace=(
        0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000107436ff8 DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 272
        1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001074703bc -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken _mountDeveloperDiskImage:withError:] + 912
        2   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000107470db0 __58-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken mountDeveloperDiskImageWithError:]_block_invoke + 564
        3   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018250abac _dispatch_client_callout + 20
        4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000182519e00 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56
        5   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000107470b20 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken mountDeveloperDiskImageWithError:] + 168
        6   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000010e839070 __37-[DVTiOSDevice(Connect) hasConnected]_block_invoke_2 + 148
        7   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000102116238 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 16
        8   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000102119ba8 __DVTDispatchGroupAsync_block_invoke + 564
        9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000182508e60 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
        10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018250abac _dispatch_client_callout + 20
        11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018250e118 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 656
        12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018250d6dc _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 596
        13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018251c31c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 396
        14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018251cb58 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 164
        15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001826c5574 _pthread_wqthread + 228
        16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001826c42c4 start_wqthread + 8
    ), DVTRadarComponentKey=261622, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not support development.}}, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=If you are certain that Xcode supports development on this device, try disconnecting and reconnecting the device., NSLocalizedFailure=This operation can fail if the version of the OS on the device is newer than the version of Xcode that is running., DVTRadarComponentKey=487927, NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to prepare device for development.}) {
        AssociatedMobileDeviceFunction = AMDeviceMountImage;
        DVTRadarComponentKey = 487927;
        NSLocalizedDescription = "Failed to prepare device for development.";
        NSLocalizedFailure = "This operation can fail if the version of the OS on the device is newer than the version of Xcode that is running.";
        NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion = "If you are certain that Xcode supports development on this device, try disconnecting and reconnecting the device.";
        NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain Code=-402653066 \"Could not support development.\" UserInfo={MobileDeviceErrorCode=(0xE8000076), com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace=(\n\t0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000107436ff8 DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 272\n\t1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001074703bc -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken _mountDeveloperDiskImage:withError:] + 912\n\t2   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000107470db0 __58-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken mountDeveloperDiskImageWithError:]_block_invoke + 564\n\t3   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018250abac _dispatch_client_callout + 20\n\t4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000182519e00 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56\n\t5   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000107470b20 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken mountDeveloperDiskImageWithError:] + 168\n\t6   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000010e839070 __37-[DVTiOSDevice(Connect) hasConnected]_block_invoke_2 + 148\n\t7   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000102116238 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 16\n\t8   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000102119ba8 __DVTDispatchGroupAsync_block_invoke + 564\n\t9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000182508e60 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32\n\t10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018250abac _dispatch_client_callout + 20\n\t11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018250e118 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 656\n\t12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018250d6dc _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 596\n\t13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018251c31c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 396\n\t14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018251cb58 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 164\n\t15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001826c5574 _pthread_wqthread + 228\n\t16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001826c42c4 start_wqthread + 8\n), DVTRadarComponentKey=261622, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not support development.}";
    }
    2022-02-24 16:35:23.893 xcodebuild[41435:8807867] [MT] iPhoneConnect: <DVTiOSDevice (0x1168722b0), Raymond’s iPhone13, iPhone, 15.4 (19E5219e), 00008110-001C3DD93A29801E> -- An error occurred whilst preparing device for development -- Failed to prepare device for development.
    Domain: com.apple.dtdevicekit
    Code: 806
    Recovery Suggestion: If you are certain that Xcode supports development on this device, try disconnecting and reconnecting the device.
    User Info: {
        AssociatedMobileDeviceFunction = AMDeviceMountImage;
        DVTRadarComponentKey = 487927;
        NSLocalizedFailure = "This operation can fail if the version of the OS on the device is newer than the version of Xcode that is running.";
    }
    --

=========================== skip the middle ============================

    warning: Stale file '/Users/gracegyu/Documents/Azure/cleverpam/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/image_picker/image_picker.framework/Headers/FLTImagePickerPlugin_Test.h' is located outside of the allowed root paths.

    warning: Stale file '/Users/gracegyu/Documents/Azure/cleverpam/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Runner' is located outside of the allowed root paths.

    warning: Stale file '/Users/gracegyu/Documents/Azure/cleverpam/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/device_info_plus.framework' is located outside of the allowed root paths.

    warning: Stale file '/Users/gracegyu/Documents/Azure/cleverpam/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/integration_test.framework' is located outside of the allowed root paths.

    warning: Stale file '/Users/gracegyu/Documents/Azure/cleverpam/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/share_plus.framework' is located outside of the allowed root paths.

    note: Removed stale file '/Users/gracegyu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gpddwqgzjbasxveiquubzegvfqbi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC.build/Script-61624EEA4A085137B50822CDE34252BB.sh'

    /Users/gracegyu/Documents/Azure/cleverpam/ios/Runner.xcodeproj: warning: The Copy Bundle Resources build phase contains this target's Info.plist file '/Users/gracegyu/Documents/Azure/cleverpam/ios/Runner/Info-Debug.plist'. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 13.
```

The result of "flutter doctor -v" is below.
Even if you connect the iPhone real device, it cannot be connected. Xcode doesn't work on iPhone either. I've tried everything, but I can't connect.
It was connected until yesterday, but from today it suddenly cannot connect.

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel dev, 1.26.0-1.0.pre, on macOS 12.0.1 21A559 darwin-arm, locale en-KR)
    • Flutter version 1.26.0-1.0.pre at /Users/gracegyu/dev/flutter
    • Framework revision 63062a6443 (1 year, 2 months ago), 2020-12-13 23:19:13 +0800
    • Engine revision 4797b06652
    • Dart version 2.12.0 (build 2.12.0-141.0.dev)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/gracegyu/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 32.0.0
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/gracegyu/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 13.1, Build version 13A1030d
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.64.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.34.0

[✓] Connected device (4 available)
    • sdk gphone64 arm64 (mobile) • emulator-5554                        • android-arm64  • Android 12 (API 31) (emulator)
    • iPhone 13 (mobile)          • 37B922DB-CECE-4299-AFBC-86A1AD5680E2 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-15-0 (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)             • macos                                • darwin-arm64   • macOS 12.0.1 21A559 darwin-arm
    • Chrome (web)                • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 98.0.4758.102
    ! Error: Unable to prepare Raymond’s iPhone13 for development.  (code -1)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because the version of XCode does not support the version of iOS installed on the iPhone. Just update XCode.